# Unable to decrement an Int value in Android SQLite DB

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-update

I am trying to increment a value in an SQLite DB (Android) but I get a fatal error of 'no such table' in the logcat and the app crushes. The table exists in the database however. Could there be something wrong with my code? Any help will be appreciated much. Here are my update code and the logcat output.

**a) Update Code**

```
public void tupdateDaysLeft(){
    if (daysLeftCur == null) {
        daysLeftCur = findDaysLeft();
    }

    if (daysLeftCur.moveToFirst()) {
        int columnIndex = daysLeftCursor.getColumnIndex(MsDbAdapter.COL_DAYSLEFT);
        int daysToDel = daysLeftCur.getInt(columnIndex);

    //  int stt = daysToDel;
    //  daysle  = stt;

    mDb.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_PRE+
                " SET "+COL_DAYSLEFT+" = "+COL_DAYSLEFT+" - 1"+
                " WHERE "+COL_ID+" = ?",
                new Object[] { columnIndex });
    }
}
```

**b)-*i* Logcat output 1**

```
07-16 23:43:36.938: E/SQLiteLog(20992): (1) no such table: TABLE_PRE
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: TABLE_PRE (code 1): , while compiling: update 

TABLE_PRE set COL_DAYSLEFT = COL_DAYSLEFT + 1 where COL_ID = ?
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1013)
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:624)
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-16 23:43:36.948: E/AndroidRuntime(20992):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
```

**b)-*ii* Logcat output 2**

```
01-01 06:31:37.701: E/AndroidRuntime(6357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 06:31:37.701: E/AndroidRuntime(6357): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 06:31:37.701: E/AndroidRuntime(6357): at com.tembk.mspre.database.MsDbAdapter.tupdateDaysLeft(MsDbAdapter.java:292)
01-01 06:31:37.701: E/AndroidRuntime(6357): at com.tembk.mspre.pre.PreStatus$3.onClick(PreStatus.java:79)
```

**c) Table Definition**

```
private static final String TABLE_PRE = "pre";
```

**EDIT**

**d) Table Constants/fields**

```
private static final String TABLE_PRE = "pre";
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_BEGINDATE = "begindate";
public static final String COL_TERMEND = "termend";
public static final String COL_DAYSLEFT = "daysleft";
public static final String COL_DATE_TIME = "pre_date_time";
```

**e) Table Creation SQL**

```
private static final String PRE_TABLE_CREATE =
    "create table " + TABLE_PRE + " ("
            + COL_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COL_BEGINDATE + " text not null, "
            + COL_TERMEND + " text not null, "
            + COL_DAYSLEFT + " integer not null, "
            + COL_DATE_TIME + " text not null " + ")";
```

Comment: Post your create statement for table `pre`

Comment: @Apoorv, I have edited the code to include the FIELD NAMES and CREATE statement. Check the 'EDIT'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using content values instead. I created a method in the database adapter and called it in my main activity passing in the values I needed. It looks rough but works fine.

**1) DB Adapter Update Method**

```
public boolean updatePreDL(Object mRowId, int daysleft, String preDateTime) {
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(COL_DAYSLEFT, daysleft);
    newValues.put(COL_DATE_TIME, preDateTime);
    return mDb.update(TABLE_PRE, newValues, COL_ID + "=" + mRowId, null) > 0;
}
```

**2) Button Click call (of the DB Adapter Update Method above)**

```
updateDays.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDbHelper.updatePreDL(MsDbAdapter.COL_ID, 
                    daysLeftCur.getInt(daysLeftCur.getColumnIndex(MsDbAdapter.COL_DAYSLEFT))-1, 
                    MsDbAdapter.COL_DATE_TIME);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The database does not know that there is are symbols named `TABLE_PRE` or `daysle` in your Java code; you have to replace them in Java.

Furthermore, `COL_ID` is likely to be the *name* of the ID column, but you need to compare with the *value* in the desired record.

```java
mDb.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_PRE+
            " SET "+COL_DAYSLEFT+" = ?"+
            " WHERE "+COL_ID+" = ?",
            new Object[] { daysle + 1, idOfTheRowToUpdate });
```

However, to increase the value, you do not need to read the old value in your code; you can do the addition directly in SQL:

```java
mDb.execSQL("UPDATE "+TABLE_PRE+
            " SET "+COL_DAYSLEFT+" = "+COL_DAYSLEFT+" + 1"+
            " WHERE "+COL_ID+" = ?",
            new Object[] { idOfTheRowToUpdate });
```

Comment: @CL., Looks promising so far, let me give it a try.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and now I get the error in **Logcat output 2** above.

Comment: A column index is not an ID value, but this has nothing to do with the NPE. `mDb` is null, but that is another problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use this:

```
mDb.execSQL("update TABLE_PRE set COL_DAYSLEFT = "+ (daysle + 1) +"  where COL_ID = ?", new Object[] {COL_ID});
}
```

Instead of this:

```
mDb.execSQL("update TABLE_PRE set COL_DAYSLEFT = daysle + 1 where COL_ID = ?", new Object[] {COL_ID});
```